# how can I greet username from php array based on HTML form input?

Tags: php

I have that HTML from / I want to make a PHP array in a checkname.php so that when the name is entered in the HTML form input it comes back saying WELCOME (NAME) / and if the name is not within the PHP array it would say user not found, tried everything and not working for me. anyone can help ?

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Greet </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Greeting App</h2>
<form  action="checkname.php" name ="form" method = "POST">
 
    <input type="text" name = "inputField" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['inputField'])) 
{
    $input = $_POST['inputField'];
    echo "Welcome: <b> $input </b>";
    

    if ($input === $_POST['inputField']) {
        echo " ,You are now signed in!</b>";
    } else{
        echo "<b>User Not Found</b>";
    }
}

$word = array("USER1", "USER2", "USER3", "USER4");


?>
```

Comment: you need to check if nameis inside array? there's `in_array` function in PHP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense: `$input = $_POST['inputField'];` then right below: `if ($input === $_POST['inputField'])`. I am guessing you meant if `($word === $_POST['inputField'])`.

anyhow you have to loop through the array and check each one, or that's how I would do it:

```
    $input = 'USER3';
    $word = array("USER1", "USER2", "USER3", "USER4");
    if(isset($input)){
        echo "Welcome: <b> $input </b>";
        foreach($word as $w){
            if($w == $input){
                echo " ,You are now signed in!</b>";
            }else{
                echo "<b>User Not Found</b>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an example in a sandbox so you can see it in action:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e92ee169d639676f014882c6ae89f229ffccecc3

#### EDIT:

@Kevin's method is definitely the way to do it, it's way more efficient.
Here's an example using his method:

```
    $input = 'USE2R3';
    $word = array("USER1", "USER2", "USER3", "USER4");
    if(isset($input)){
        echo "Welcome: $input";
        if(in_array($input, $word, true)){
            echo ", You are now signed in!";
        }else{
            echo ", Signin Failed!";
        }
    }
```

In sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8a25a566f79ef3472c50aa2422d815bdccaeadd

Thank you kevin because you just also taught me something :)

#### EDIT#2:

Since OP cannot take his time to state his question properly, here's the third edit after I just completely made the thing for you, here you go, it works 100% & tested on my website........ Google my friend, it is a life saver. Please try it next time.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Greet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Greeting App</h2>
        <form action="checkname.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input required type="text" name="inputField">
            <input type="submit" name="checkname" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['checkname'])){
        $input = $_POST['inputField'];
        $word = array("USER1", "USER2", "USER3", "USER4");
        echo "Welcome: $input";
        if(in_array($input, $word, true)){
            echo(", You are now signed in!");
        }else{
            echo(", Signin Failed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: but this will only work if USER3 is the put in the form ? I want the form to accept any of the names in the array and SHOW the name and say WELCOME (NAME) You're signed in .. if the name is not in array then user not found .. will this work for any of the names within the array ?

Comment: ok, but this is not working with my HTML FORM !! can you check the HTML form and tell me if I need to change something there, I'm close but something is still not working for me ! it automatically takes to Welcome: USE2R3, Signin Failed! in all cases / I want it to match what the user inputs in the HTML FORM and compares it the the users in the PHP array

Comment: Crimin4L ? what u mean to a different page !!

Comment: YES the PHP code is in checkname.php ?/// but it's not working with MY HTML form input !! I think my whole problem now is how to link it to the HTML form

Comment: !!!! well do you know how to make it work with the HTML form ?

Comment: OMG / man / I went over both HTML and PHP now / makes perfect sense / works 100% THANX A MILLION :)